# How to set Radio Button Colors

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to change my radio button colors while maintaining my bindings. May I ask how abouts I do that?

I tried 2 ways, setting css inline and into a style sheet. Both didn't have an effect.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div >
            <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedGroup, "Red", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn-red" }) Number of spots available @Model.Red</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div >
            <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedGroup, "Yellow", new { @style = "color:Yellow;" }) Number of spots available @Model.Yellow</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div >
            <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.SelectedGroup, "Green", new { @style = "color:Green;" }) Number of spots available @Model.Green</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vddyax

I'm trying to have it look something like this

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible do that, instead of doing this create radio button image of which color you want and with the help of css you can put this image on top of radio button

Comment: Epic case of LMGTFY

Comment: As a side note, the 2nd parameter is the `value` of the radio button